# How to combine lists with respect to precedence

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, operator-precedence

I have a List of strings like this :

```
List<string> andOrList = new List<string>();
andOrList.Add("AND");
andOrList.Add("OR");
andOrList.Add("AND");
```

And I have 4 lists to combine :

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(new int[] { 19, 23, 29 });
List<int> list2 = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 4, 29 });
List<int> list3 = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 5, 23 });
List<int> list4 = new List<int>(new int[] { 2, 4, 19 });
```

I want to make a new list from these 4 lists using ANDs and ORs from andOrList. Since AND has higher precedence than OR first I will apply ANDs so I will have these :

```
   var tempList1 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
   var tempList2 = list3.Intersect(list4).ToList();
```

And finally combine these two templists because there is an OR :

```
var resulList = tempList1.Union(tempList2);
```

As you can see it's possible to do this by hand when there is defined number of lists and defined number of ANDs and ORs. But I couldn't figure out how to do it programmatically when there are n number of Lists to combine and n-1 number of ANDs and ORs. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: I think that you will have to write a kind of operator-precedence parser.

Comment: @aloisdg a different version of Reverse Polish Notation?

Comment: you can rely on RPN, but it is not mandatory

Comment: @aloisdg Should I write something like this:First find ANDs and intersect them and then Union the rest?

Comment: What should happen if you have { "AND", "AND", "OR", "OR", "AND" }?

Comment: @Enigmativity for the four lists in the question or for another 6 lists?

Comment: @jason - For as many lists as are needed. What's the logic you need for those 5 operators? Where are the values used and where are intermediate results used?

Comment: @jason - Should the values just be inserted between each operator? And then you need 6 sets of values for my example?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes for your example, I need 6 lists. ANDs and ORs are inserted between those lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest splitting execution into *two* stages:

```
1. Performs all `AND`s
2. Perform  all `OR`s
```

E.g.

```
   a & b & c | d | e & f & g | h  ==       // put the right order
  (a & b & c) | (d) | (e & f & g) | (h) == // perform ANDs
   a_b_c | d | e_f_g | h ==                // perform ORs
   final result
```

in your case

```
  {19, 23, 29} & {1, 4, 29} | {1, 5, 23} & {2, 4, 19} ==     // put the right order
  ({19, 23, 29} & {1, 4, 29}) | ({1, 5, 23} & {2, 4, 19}) == // perform ANDs
  {29} | {} ==                                               // perform ORs
  {29}
```

Implementation

```
private static IEnumerable<T> CombinatorOrAnd<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sources, 
                                                 IEnumerable<string> actions) {
  List<IEnumerable<T>> orList = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

  // First, do all ANDs

  bool isFirst = true;
  IEnumerable<T> temp = null;

  using (var en = actions.GetEnumerator()) {
    foreach (var argument in sources) {
      if (isFirst) {
        temp = argument;
        isFirst = false;

        continue;
      }

      en.MoveNext();

      if (en.Current == "AND")
        temp = temp.Intersect(argument);
      else {
        orList.Add(temp);

        temp = argument;
      }
    }
  }

  orList.Add(temp);

  // Finally, perform all ORs 
  return orList.Aggregate((s, a) => s.Union(a));
}
```

Test

```
  List<int> list1 = new List<int>(new int[] { 19, 23, 29 });
  List<int> list2 = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 4, 29 });
  List<int> list3 = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 5, 23 });
  List<int> list4 = new List<int>(new int[] { 2, 4, 19 });

  List<string> andOrList = new List<string>();
  andOrList.Add("AND");
  andOrList.Add("OR");
  andOrList.Add("AND");

  var result = CombinatorOrAnd(new List<int>[] { list1, list2, list3, list4}, andOrList);

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result.OrderBy(item => item)));
```

Outcome

```
  29
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the belated answer, but I had this open in the background. The idea was pretty much the same: do the `AND`s first, but to do this by mutating (a copy of) the input list.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ProcessAndOr(List<string> andOrList, params List<int>[] Input)
{
    var lst = new List<IEnumerable<int>>(Input);
    for(int i = andOrList.Count -1  ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        if(andOrList[i] == "AND")
        {
            lst[i] = lst[i].Intersect(lst[++i]);
            lst.RemoveAt(i--);
        }
    return lst.SelectMany(l=>l).Distinct();
}
```

The example could be called with `var resultList = ProcessAndOr(andOrList, list1,list2,list3,list4);` and produces `29`

PS, the reverse order isn't really necessary but is done to be able to use a single variable for iteration.